# Parallel push Images using same API to save time

Tags: angular, parallel-processing

In Agular application, I am trying to push images to backend GCS using one API which is in the `uploadImages` function in MyService file. The API takes in only `formData` so adding file in the form. Using RxJs `Observables` and `forkJoin` trying to push images in parallel, for example if user adds 3 images this this API will be called 3 times and run in parallel to save time, but only one image is getting uploaded and getting 3 response but all are for first image. I suspect duplicate of subscription is happening but don't know how to fix this. Below is the sample code:

```
pushImageDatabase(imageFiles): Observable<any[]> {
          const uploadObservables = imageFiles.map((row) => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("gcs_fullpath", row['gcs_path']);
          formData.append("file", row['gcs_file']);
          return this.MyService.uploadImages(formData).pipe(
                      catchError((error) => {
                      console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
                      return error;
                    })
                  );
              });
          return forkJoin(uploadObservables) as Observable<any[]>;
        }

this.pushImageDatabase(this.imageFiles).subscribe({
                        next: (results) => {
                            console.log("All images uploaded successfully.", results);
                            },
                        error: (error) => {
                            console.error("Some image uploads failed:", error);
                    },
                    });
```

How to remove duplicate subscription and run one API in parallel. Tried using RxJs `forkJoin` but nothing is working and API is being hit only one time and only one image is getting pushed to backend GCS.